# Accessing TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TabBarController with 5 icons. In all 5 ViewControllers I have redundant code to update the badges of the TabBarController.

This is my redundant code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.latestTableOverView.reloadData()

    // Update the badge:
    self.updateBadges()
}

func updateBadges() {

    (tabBarController!.tabBar.items![0] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(0)
    (tabBarController!.tabBar.items![1] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(1)
    (tabBarController!.tabBar.items![3] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(3)
    (tabBarController!.tabBar.items![4] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(4)
}
```

The `getBadgeValueFor` is a function in my `helper.swift` file:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

func getBadgeValueFor(wich: Int) -> String? {
    // calculating the badge here...
}
:
// more stuff here
```

To reduce code redundancy I want to move `updateBadges` to my helper class, too. But from there, I can´t access the tabBarController. So if I simply copy the fun `updateBadges` to my helper file, it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can pass the tabBarController itself to the method as an argument.and just call the method form the view controller.

   ```
   func updateBadges(tabBarController : UITabBarController) {
   (tabBarController!.tabBar.items![0] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(0)
   (tabBarController!.tabBar.items![1] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(1)
   (tabBarController!.tabBar.items![3] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(3)
   (tabBarController!.tabBar.items![4] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(4)}
   ```
2. If you want to change the badges only when the tabs are changed, you can set the parent view controller OR the app delegate as `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and call the update badge method in `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method.
   However, you still need to keep a reference to the tab bar controller in the delegate class and pass the tab bar controller to the update badges method as an argument.
3. But passing the tab bar controller to the method restricts you to call it only from a context which has direct access to tab bar controller object. To avoid this, you can have a reference to the tab bar controller in the helper class. And add method to register a tab bar for updates.

   ```
   static var myTabBarController : UITabBarController?

   static func registerTabBarController(tbc : UITabBarController) {
   myTabBarController = tbc}
   ```

You will have to register the tab bar controller form the parent or from the app delegate if its the root view.

You can then perform all updates on this object

```
static func updateBadges() {

    (myTabBarController?.tabBar.items![0] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(0)
    (myTabBarController?.tabBar.items![1] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(1)
    (myTabBarController?.tabBar.items![3] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(3)
    (myTabBarController?.tabBar.items![4] as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = getBadgeValueFor(4)
}
```

The optional call makes sure that this does not crash even if the tab bar controller object is not set.
The object and the functions being static ensure the you do not have to instantiate the helper.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function in helper class which will take the `viewController` instance as a parameter.
Then from your view controller call that function with self as a parameter.
Inside the function in the helper class, you can access the `tabBarController` from the `viewController` Instance.

helper class :

```
func update_badge(vc : ViewController)
{

    vc.tabBarController .../// access like this

}
```

*the code may have syntax errors